# Is it a good practice to use Active Directory groups for access control

Tags: active-directory, scalability, access-control, wan

In a organization with lots (hundreds) of internal systems, and lots (thousands) of users, and   lots (dozens) of Domain Controllers sites, all WAN-connected, is it a good practice to use  Active Directory as a SSO provider and its groups for access control implementation?

Any significant scalability, performance or management issues I should be aware before deciding for it?

Comment: This might be a better question for [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com/)

Answer (score 1):

In my organization with 100,000+ users, we make use of active directory. You will certainly not have an issue with scalability.